# Ожидание запуска процесса на Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, процесс

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, реально ли в Delphi отследить запуск процесса и завершить его при старте? Если реально, не могли бы вы подтолкнуть, подсказать - в какую сторону мне копать. Сейчас гуглил, но увидел только примеры с ожиданием завершения процесса.

Спасибо.

Comment: Для чего вам это нужно? Если вы хотите ограничить количество запущенных копий своего приложения, то все намного проще.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что значит "отследить запуск процесса", и чем это отличается от "найти запущенный процесс"?

Во втором случае, приложение периодически проводит поиск процесса.
При желании, можно покопать в сторону MessagesAPI, помнится, там можно было устанавливать уведомления для своего процесса на системные события (Win).